# How can i download file with "download" attribute in HTML?

Tags: html

I want to download file with "download" attribute. I used "download" attribute inside `<a>` tag but when I click on the link  instead of downloading the file it just opened new page and showed me the file. How can i fix it? Noted that I have a folder called "testing" and inside that folder i have another folder called "file" which store "database_assignment.pdf" and outside the "file" folder but inside "testing" folder I have another file called "index.html".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>download file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="file/database_assignment.pdf" download>download here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that but…

- It must be a same-origin request
- You must use HTTP(S) and not a local `file:` scheme URL

Comment: Hii can you tell me a bit more about that because im so confused now

Comment: What, specifically, is confusing about that? Have you tried typing terms you don't understand into a search engine?

Comment: I did some research about the download and I did exactly what people did but it worked for them but not for me.

Comment: The thing that I confused about is " You must use HTTP(S) and not a local file: scheme URL"

Comment: So does the URL in the address bar of your browser start with `http://`, `https://`, `file://` or something else?

Comment: it's file:// sir

Comment: Then that is your problem. You need a webserver.

Comment: After hosted to firebase for testing it's worked. Thanks you so much sir for your help.